# Unix regular expression for java single line comments

Tags: regex, unix

I need to write UNIX regular expression that matches all lines according to following :

1. All lines containing comment of the form //
   eg. **valid matches -**

```sh
// .alkjaklfsldk
        /////sldkfjslkdf
ksdflksdjf //
```

**invalid :**

```sh
lkajdlaks
dslkfjskldjflksd
```

2. All lines starting with a lower-case letter and ending with a lower-case letter
3. All lines that do not end with a digit unless this digit is 2.

`Each expression must be enclosed between characters ^ $.`

I came up with the following -

1. //   (I tested simple egrep // filename.txt works)
   But the highlighted line says it must be enclosed between characters ^ $. Don't understand how to achieve that
2. [a-z].[a-z]$  -- Here it doesn't start with ^
3. .[013456789]$

I am mainly confused about the highlighted part. And also if the above expressions are correct

Comment: But in `// .alkjaklfsldk` it doesn't start with a lowercase letter

Comment: These are three different regular expressions. For each part a different regular expression needs to be produced

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Hints: `.` matches any character. `.*` matches any character repeated 0 or any times. You can use `^` in `[^...]` to match characters that are **not** in the specified set.

Comment: Please don't use comments to add clarification or requested information, [edit] your question instead.